# Session variables getting lost when navigating to a different controller (& AJAX requests), however session vars set during Session_Start is intact

Tags: .net, ajax, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

This question is about an issue we are facing with a .net framework based MVC app that uses windows authentication. The variables set during `Session_Start` seems to be just fine and available throughout, but any session variable set after the fact seems to be lost. In the output below, first line is where we set a session variable. The exception is when I am trying to access it in a different page. However if you notice other session variables set during Session_Start are still available. This is issue 1.

```
Current session value (home): zero
---
(different page)
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ---removed---
   at ---removed---
Id (from session): 0
Name (from session): Admin
Email (from session): admin@admin.com
```

We explored further and it also seems like AJAX requests are creating a whole new session. This is issue 2. We have tried a number of things - update the $.ajax call to xhrfields/withCrdentials, tried setting an AutoRedirectMode using the FriendlyUrls package, tried ignoring a few routes suggested, etc. But nothing helps. So any pointers regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. Looks like some process (most likely the anti-virus) is messing with the bin directory causing the application to be restarted again and again. So we added the `fcnMode` attribute to the `httpRuntime` element and set it to Disabled so as to disable the behavior for now.